# bash shell script to subtract milliseconds from a given timestamp

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash shell script where I take an inputDate string and then add some months to it to get a new date and then I format it as timestamp with milliseconds as below

```
START=2017_01_01;
i=1;
inputdate="${START//_/-}"
somedate=$(date -d "$inputdate + $i month" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S-%3NZ")
echo "somedate="$somedate
```

The output is - 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z 
Is it possible to subtract a millisecond from this, so I get a previous date something like 2016-12-31T23:59:59.000Z for the above example?
Last dates are not fixed for the months, so I am trying to see if I can subtract a millisecond from a given month to get the last date with timestamp for the previous month. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your objective? You can subtract just one day to get the day before your START date.

Comment: Just subtract one second: `"$inputdate + $i month - 1 second"` Or 0.001 seconds (a millisecond) if you want.

Comment: I need to subtract a millisecond and not a second. I could subtract a day to get a previous day but then I dont know how to format it to get 2016-12-31T23:59:59.000Z  (Note that I need the last day to have timestamp showing as 'T23:59:59.000Z' and not 'T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: @user1892775, Well, in your question you say "millisecond" but your example shows only a second. Anyway, see the edit to my comment above. Just subtract 0.001 seconds.

Comment: @ooga you are right. And that works, thanks

Comment: @user1892775  if it works, feel free to post it as an answer ; ) so we can close the question